# Amplify DataStore: How to know when sync is finished?

Tags: flutter, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, datastore

**How can we know that DataStore has finished the sync?**

When doing the first `await DataStore.query(MyEntity)` after the user logged in, DataStore is returning right away and not waiting for the data to be synced with the cloud.

I want to wait for the sync to be completed and put a loading when the data isn't synced yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to events on the datastore channel with `Amplify.Hub.listen.`

details:

```
 subscription = Amplify.Hub.listen([HubChannel.DataStore], (dynamic hubEvent) async {
      switch (hubEvent.eventName) {
        case 'networkStatus':
          _amplifyIsUp.value = hubEvent.payload.active;
          break;
        case 'subscriptionsEstablished':
          _amplifyMessage.value = 'Starting to sync from cloud...';
          break;
        case 'syncQueriesStarted':
          _amplifyIsSyncing.value = true;
          _amplifyMessage.value = 'Syncing...';
          break;
        case 'modelSynced':
          ModelSyncedEvent mse = hubEvent.payload;

          _amplifyMessage.value = '${mse.modelName} has been sync\'d from cloud...';
          break;
        case 'syncQueriesReady':
          _amplifyMessage.value = 'Done!';
          _amplifyIsSyncing.value = false;
          
          ///do your bits here
          onSyncsReady.call();
          
          break;
        case 'ready':
          _amplifyIsSyncing.value = false;

          break;
        case 'subscriptionDataProcessed':
   
          SubscriptionDataProcessedEvent sdpe = hubEvent.payload;
                  _amplifyMessage.value = 'Syncing ${sdpe.element.model.classType.modelName()}...';
         if (sdpe.element.model is DeviceStatus) {
            DeviceStatus ds = sdpe.element.model as DeviceStatus;
            if (ds.clientID == _clientService.client.id && ds.status == Status.REQUESTSTATUS) {
              _statusService.performHeartbeat();
              } 
          }
          break;
        case 'outboxMutationEnqueued':
          _amplifyIsSyncing.value = true;
          _amplifyHasDirt.value = true;
          break;
        case 'outboxMutationProcessed':
          OutboxMutationEvent ome = hubEvent.payload;
          _amplifyIsSyncing.value = false;
          break;
        case 'outboxStatus':
          OutboxStatusEvent ose = hubEvent.payload;
          if (ose.isEmpty) {
            _amplifyIsSyncing.value = false;
            _amplifyHasDirt.value = false;
          } else {
            _amplifyHasDirt.value = true;
          }

          break;
      }
    });
```

boop

Answer (score 1):

make your model class observable so that it can check for data in realtime

```
   Amplify.DataStore.observeQuery(MyEntity.classType).listen((event) {
  if (event.isSynced) {//boolean value
    print("Synced Successfully!");
    // even you can get synced data here also
      List< MyEntity> items = event.items;
  } else {
    //Show ProgressBar Here
    print("Fetching Data From Cloud");
  }
});
```